# How to find the name of a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How do I get the name of a column? What's the query for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: All good answers here.. But what if I wanted the column name of just one specific column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SHOW COLUMNS` command can be used to retrieve column names in a table

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**SHOW COLUMNS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) which displays information about the columns in a given table.

Answer (score 0):

`DESCRIBE tableName` will give you the names of all the columns in the table.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty broad context..

You could try something as simple as

```
describe `table_name`;
```